# Can the word 'While' mean 'On the one hand' in the beginning of the sentence?

Tags: word-choice, conjunctions, sentence-meaning

The usage of the word ***while*** as ***on the one hand*** at the beginning of the sentences looks confusing to me.

I tried looking for threads addressing this question on this site. Unfortunately, I couldn't find any. Please give me a few examples where ***while*** would mean ***on the one hand***.

Comment: [CED](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/while) has << **while** conjunction (ALTHOUGH)
 
B2
(also formal _whilst_)
despite the fact that; although:
 • _While I accept that he's not perfect in many respects, I do actually like the man._
 • _While I fully understand your point of view, I also have some sympathy with Michael's._ >>

Answer (score 1):

I think it is alright to use "while" with the connotation of "on the one hand", but they are not perfectly interchangeable.

> ***While*** the book has not received many positive critics, it has been selling like hot cakes.

Here *while* could be replaced by ***Although on the one hand***

> Although on the one hand the book has not received many positive critics, (on the other hand) it has been selling like hot cakes.

Answer (score 0):

[CED](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/while) says one meaning of "while" is

> compared with the fact that; but

The examples they gave for it are as follows. Note: "but" could replace "while" in these sentences.

> • He gets £50,000 a year while I get a
> meagre £20,000!
>
> • Tom is very extrovert and confident
> while Katy's shy and quiet.
>
> • I do all the housework while he just
> does the dishes now and again.

These could be rewritten:

• Compared with the fact that I get a meagre £20,000 a year, he gets £50,000!

• Compared with the fact that Katy's shy and quiet, Tom is very extrovert and confident.

• Compared with the fact that he just does the dishes now and again, I do all the housework.

Therefore, we can say, amid a sentence, "while" could mean "but".

At the head of a sentence, "while" may mean not "on the one hand" but "compared with the fact that". "While" makes subordinate clauses, beginning sentences with which requires a comma. Replacing "while" with "on the one hand" means making a coordinate clause, e.g. "On the one hand I get a meagre £20,000 a year". To add the rest of the sentence ("He gets £50,000!"), one needs a semicolon, so "on the one hand" doesn't serve the purpose that "while" does.

Comment: It doesn't. OP has misunderstood. "While" makes subordinate clauses, beginning sentences with which requires a comma. Replacing "while" with "on the one hand" means making a coordinate clause, e.g. "On the one hand I get a meagre £20,000 a year". To add the rest of the sentence ("he gets £50,000!"), one needs a semicolon, so "on the one hand" doesn't serve the purpose that "while" does. I am also adding this to my answer.

Comment: Thanks for answering. After a bit of struggle, I managed to find the following link where it is mentioned that 'While' can mean 'On the one hand'.         https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/56277/distinguishing-between-although-and-while

Comment: @naveen-kumar I see that explanation was very basic. The author used square brackets ("[]"), to effectively say "on the one/other hand" is not a replacement for "while" but an add-on. "While" and "on the one/other hand" are not synonyms but used together for the sake of clarity. To check, consult a [thesaurus](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/on%20the%20other%20hand).